# How to add background and with Strip image on same time on front side of Pass on Passbook in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, passbook

I am working on passbook integration and added card successfully but I am stuck on how to strip image with background image. 
When I use "eventTicket" style type then I can add background image but no strip image but when I use "coupon" then I can add strip image but no background image. I also tested rest of three types also but didn't work.
Now I am looking for any help that I can add both on same time. If possible or apple allow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer - you can't.  Event tickets are the only pass types that support background images, but only with a Thumbnail image.  The combination of Background and Strip is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of Background Image and Strip image is not possible.  See Table 3.1 and Figure 3.4 of the [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW45).

**Note:** *"If you specify a strip image, do not specify a background image or a thumbnail."*

[image: Table 3.1]

[image: Figure 3.4]

Comment: Do not post [images of code or text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are inaccessible to those with visual impairments, and are often blocked by corporate proxies. Especially now that Markdown supports tables, this answer could be improved by making the data available to all.

Comment: Feel free to edit it by all means.  This post was added almost a year before the Meta post you have referenced was added - thanks for making me aware.